# Sending data from python to an esp over telnet

Tags: python, tcp, telnet, esp8266, telnetlib

I'm working on a project that involves sending information from an ESP8266 by TCP/IP over telnet to python, and to be honest its my first time using telnetlib.
I wrote this small code for testing, but when I execute it, it returns "'in ' requires string as left operand, not bytes". Can someone help me out please?

```
import telnetlib
HOST="192.168.0.67"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, "23")

tn.write("Hello World\n")
print (tn.read_all())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read_all()` method in `telnetlib` returns bytes rather than a string. You can verify this by reading the [documentation for `telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html).

`print()` takes a string as its argument - as the error you mentioned references. You'll need to convert the bytes returned by `telnetlib`.

Try using the `str()` function:

```
print (str(tn.read_all(), 'UTF-8'))
```

the `UTF-8` argument specifies the encoding of the string, in this case 8 bit Unicode.

As an aside, Telnet is a deprecated protocol for doing remote login. It's a bit pointless to use it just to transfer data. You're better off using a raw TCP connection. Telnet is a thin layer above TCP that adds complexity and overhead you almost certainly do not need.